# How can I make all tables contain certain columns in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Let's assume I'm going to create 10 tables and they have 4 columns in common. Is there an easy way to generate the migration without specifying all 4 columns in each of 10 table's migration file?

Comment: That begs the question of why one would want to do that.  Are you open to refactoring the DB?  I'm guessing there may be a Rails way to do this but I am secretly hoping not.

Comment: @steveklein My motivation is to add certain fields to each table that gets created (e.g. created_by). I came from Grails background and very new to Ruby on Rails. In Grails, you make a base class that contains certain fields, and every data model that inherit this base class will contain the same fields. Rails doesn't work the same way apparently since you don't specify the fields in model class. What I want is something like t.timestamps method in migration file. It adds created_at and updated_at. Is there a way to make a customized method like this to encapsulate certain fields?

Comment: The point of a relational database is to normalize your data in such a way as to eliminate redundancy. Repeating four columns in ten different tables defeats the purpose.

Comment: Rails tables get columns for `created_at` and `updated_at` automatically.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Sorry I guess I didn't make myself very clear. I'm not talking about four columns with the same data in 10 tables. I'm talking about the columns with the same name, like timestamp columns that Rails added automatically (created_at, updated_at). Suppose I also want to add created_by and updated_by to each table, is specifying each columns in the migration file every time I create a new model the only way? Or is there a way to encapsulate them to a method call or something alike?

Comment: @steveklein Right, and I'm wondering is there a way to make a customized method similar to "timestamps" to add several fields by just calling that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy to create your own migration helper.  I'll create a simple one that adds `created_by` and `updated_by` columns with a migration helper called `userstamps`.

Create an new initializer file `config/initializers/userstamps.rb`:

```
module UserstampMigrationHelper
  def userstamps
    column :created_by, :integer
    column :updated_by, :integer
  end
end

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition.include(UserstampMigrationHelper)
```

Now you can use it in a migration:

```
class WidgetsMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :widgets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.userstamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! I'm new to Rails community and wondering if there is documentation for this kind of technique.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never come across any documentation for this.